# how to make parse of list(string) not list(char) in parse argument of list?

Tags: python-3.x, list, flask, flask-restful

I use flask_restful in flask

My code like:

```
from flask_restful import Resource, reqparse

apilink_parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
apilink_parser.add_argument('provider_id', type=int,required=True)
apilink_parser.add_argument('name', type=str, required=True)
apilink_parser.add_argument('func_id', type=int)
apilink_parser.add_argument('method', type=str)
apilink_parser.add_argument('url', type=str)
apilink_parser.add_argument('parameter',type=list)
apilink_parser.add_argument("expectreturn", type=list)


@marshal_with(apilink_fields)
def post(self):
    args = apilink_parser.parse_args()
    print(args)
    # user owns the task
    task = APILink.create(**args)
    return task, 201
```

My json post data like:

```
{ 
"name":"riskiqwhois",
"provider_id":1,
"func_id":1,
"url":"myurl",
"parameter":["query"],  //******//
"expectreturn":[],
"method":"post"
 }
```

but when I print the arrgs the result is:

```
 {
 'provider_id': 1, 
 'name': 'riskiqwhois', 
 'func_id': 1, 
 'method': 'post', 
 'url': 'myurl', 
 'parameter': ['q', 'u', 'e', 'r', 'y'], //******//
 'expectreturn': None
  }
```

I want 
You can see I want parameter is list of string which is only one element named "query", but the real parameter tranlate into the database is  ['q', 'u', 'e', 'r', 'y'], How to make the parameter is list of string not list of char? how to make sure the data is list(string)?

Answer (score 2):

Well, you forgot to set `action="append"` and you should change from type=list to type=str.
If not, you will still be getting a result like [['q', 'u', 'e', 'r', 'y']].

```
...
apilink_parser.add_argument('parameter',type=str, action='append')
apilink_parser.add_argument("expectreturn", type=str, action='append')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this problem by adding **action="append"** to your request parser
like below

```
apilink_parser.add_argument('parameter',type=str,action="append")
apilink_parser.add_argument("expectreturn", type=list,action="append")
```

this will return you below output

```
 {
 'provider_id': 1, 
 'name': 'riskiqwhois', 
 'func_id': 1, 
 'method': 'post', 
 'url': 'myurl', 
 'parameter': ['query'],
 'expectreturn': None
  }
```