# argparse POST an array or list

Tags: python, rest, api, flask

I am trying to parse a *list* of one or more "ministers/speakers", (by minister_id) per service.  In a RESTful call to API.  I'm using argparse:

```
from flask_restful import Resource, reqparse

parser = reqparse.RequestParser()

parser.add_argument('service_id',
    type=int,
    required=True,
    help="Every service needs a service id.")

parser.add_argument('church_id',
    type=int,
    required=True,
    help="Every service needs a church id.")

parser.add_argument('speakers',
    type = list,
    default=[],
    required=True,
    help="Every service needs at least one minister.")
```

Here is my request:

```
    {
    "service_id": 1,
    "church_id": 1,
    "speakers": [1,2]
    }
```

And here is my response:

```
   {
    "message": {
        "speakers": "Every service needs at least one minister."
    }
}
```

For whatever reason it isnt reading [1,2] into a list...

I have tried:

- **type=list** my error: *see above*
- **nargs**   my error: *TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'nargs'*
- **Type=int** my error: *"TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable"*

Comment: Show us how you are trying to apply this `parser` to the `response`.  It doesn't do that automatically.  `argparse` is intended to parse the commandline list (`sys.argv`) provided by the shell.  I've never seen it used in `REST` context.

Comment: `from flask_restful import Resource, reqparse` -- `parser = reqparse.RequestParser()`

Comment: I updated the question to include the declaration

Comment: `reqparse` is `flask's` own json parser.  It is not `argparse` though the syntax looks similar.  https://stackoverflow.com/q/48864939/901925

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to achieve equivalent functionality for passing multiple values for one argument with `reqparse`. Use the `action=` keyword argument, `action=split`or `action=append`.

With `split`, you will pass in a comma separated string and it will do something like `<<argument>>.split(',')`, returning a list when parsed.

Your request would then look like:

```
 {
    "service_id": 1,
    "church_id": 1,
    "speakers": "1,2"
}
```

Another option is to use the `append` action, which I think you are looking for. It will keep the type `int` (with the `type=int` keyword argument). With append, the speakers argument given in the example will parse as a list. You would pass the same list as an argument:

```
 {
    "service_id": 1,
    "church_id": 1,
    "speakers": [1,2]
}
```

From the command line, you would use the append argument multiple arguments like:

`curl http://api.example.com -d "speakers=bob" -d "speakers=sue" -d "speakers=joe"`

See the [documentation](https://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reqparse.html#multiple-values-lists) for more details.

Comment: Please also include the request itself, there is slightly different behavior for requparse based on where in the request the arguments are included.